# Skip pre-commit hook in "npm version" command

Tags: javascript, git, npm, pre-commit-hook

`npm version` commits the change to package.json and creates a tag. Is there a way to prevent commit hook from being executed while using this command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure why this functionality didn't exist in `npm` before, but I contributed it a little while ago, as I needed it myself. It shipped with `npm@5.4.0`. To use it, set the config option `commit-hooks = false` in your `.npmrc` and the underlying `git` call will not run commit hooks when creating the version commit. If you only want to disable commit hooks on a single versioning, you can run something similar to:

```
npm version --no-commit-hooks minor
```

or alternatively:

```
npm version --commit-hooks false minor
```

Comment: The docs say the flag is 'commit-hooks' and it takes a boolean. Might be worth updating the answer with the link, too: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version#commit-hooks.

Comment: @loujaybee The way npm processes CLI flags allows interpreting boolean flags prefixed with `--no-` as  equivalent to setting the flag to `false`. I chose to demonstrate that form for the sake of brevity. However I added an example to demonstrate that other command form for greater completeness.

Answer (score 14):

According to [npm cli docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) you can  skip the generation of a git tag by using

```
npm --no-git-tag-version version
```

Comment: Thank you. Docs doesn't really say "only"... Commit is one of the steps but the docs say nothing about controlling the commit behaviour. There may be some undocumented option or package.json configuration.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to avoid touching `git` at all. With `--no-commit-hooks`, it complained when working directory wasn't clean.

Comment: This one worked for me, not the accepted answer. NPM v8.19.2

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)

> **commit-hooks**
>
> - Default: true
> - Type: Boolean
>
> Run git commit hooks when using the `npm version` command.

If you simply want to allow this one time run the follow

```
npm version --no-commit-hooks patch|minor|major
```

To control this permanently, run the following command

```
npm config set commit-hooks false
```

Or add this line to your `.npmrc` file

`commit-hooks=false`

Comment: Using .npmrc file is the best bet. As humans we're great at forgetting to include special flags.

Comment: but .npmrc may not be included in a repo so it is up to your use case

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above solutions, nothing worked for me.

the below command works well.

```
git commit -m "message" --no-verify
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in a Git repo if you're looking for no tag and no commit but just the increment. (Replace patch with major or minor depending on your use case)

```
npm --no-git-tag-version version patch
```